# How can I append the same byte to a file a specified number of times?

Tags: bash

I have the following code:

`yes "$(echo -e "\xff")" | head -n 10 > SomeFile.bin`

Which writes 10 times 0xFF and 0x0A (newline) to SomeFile.bin. But my objective is to fill the file with FF.

Is there a way to print only consecutive 0xFF values instead? Without adding a newline every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
printf '\xFF%.s' {1..10} >SomeFile.bin
```

Comment: Can it work with a variable? i.e. `printf '\xFF%.s' {1..$foo} >SomeFile.bin`

Comment: @JCSB not without eval, like `eval "printf '\\xFF%.s' {1..$n}"`